# MongoDB: использование count() одновременно с limit() и skip()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Добрый день! Делаю пагинацию. Для ее создания мне нужна информация о кол-ве документов удовлетворяющих запросу. Используя `count()` самостоятельно, я это сделать могу. Но знаю, что в запрос можно добавлять несколько методов/условий. Например,

```
collection.find({"age":20}).skip(3).limit(2).toArray(function(err, result){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            db.close();
    });
```

Можно ли в этот запрос добавить `count()`, чтобы получить общее кол-во документов, которые соответствуют запросу? Или может можно, из запроса, что показан выше, как-то вытащить по другому, нужную мне информацию ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21803290/get-a-count-of-total-documents-with-mongodb-when-using-limit

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ - нельзя.
Надо два запроса